# My Project and User Control in ASP Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I build a user control in C# as follows:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=55475405211482553976

I need to use this in ASP.NET page, But I couldn't do it. Is there any idea for using this control in ASP Page?

Comment: You want to use UserContol on your MVC View RAzor page? Am i get you right?

Comment: I want to use this control in simple ASP Page. @teovankot is it clear or any tips?

Comment: Well, don't you want to use `iframe` on your ASP page and load your controll inside `iframe`?

Comment: now, is it clear? @teovankot

Comment: @teovankot maybe it's a good idea to using ifram, is there any example recommend by you with  my code?

Comment: @LoveComplexity i can't understand what do you mean example with your code. Your code is just separate page. And `iframe` tag just load this page inside your page. I add answer with some explanation and debug steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just place on your ASP page html like this:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="your-aspx-page.aspx" height="100%" width="100%">
```

You just need to write right path to `src` attribute.

First make sure that your `.aspx` page works well separatly (just open your page in browser) and then `iframe` tag should do all the work about load page on your asp page for you.

Comment: Thanks Teo,  did you try this page with my code as attached in my question ?

Comment: @MioUnio `src` tag should contain link to your `aspx` page where your controll located. I mean you should create aspx (WebForms) page, place your controll on it and then use iframe on your asp page.

Comment: my question say we create user control in C# not in ASP file.